# Change values in a query with vba filters

Tags: sql, vba, postgresql, case

I have multiple vba filters I need to apply to my sql query. Column yellow is the column I want to alter with filters. I have more filters but this is the outline. Column roi has to change every time new average is applied to column yellow. Because formula for roi is

`ROUND(((col_az*0.7-1.4-6-5-yellow) / NULLIF((yellow),0)*100),0)`

- Apply filter to f_n_s = 'yes' and roi < 10
- Every visible row in yellow must have the formula AVERAGE(max1,max2)
- Every visible row in yellow must have the formula AVERAGE(max1,max2,max3)
- Every visible row in yellow must be max5

  ```
  SELECT *,
      CASE
          WHEN f_n_s IN ('yes') AND roi < 10 THEN ROUND(((max1+max2)/2),2)
      END as yellow
  FROM

  [Subqueries]
  ```

This is what I do but I can't add the other filters. I don't even know if it's doable.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: simplify! [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how yellow is a function of roi, but roi is a function of yellow; isn't that a circular reference?

Comment: Roi's formula includes column yellow. So every time a value changes in yellow (with averages of max1,max2..) roi changes too. But I also filter yellow with roi < 10 so when roi changes for example 9 to 14 then yellow’s value changes (because of roi<10) . It’s a bit complicated.